# Track that plays during the fight scene in episode 22 of Parasyte

Tags: music, parasyte

Can't find the track in the OST, it's played during the fight scene in episode 22 where migi slices the neck of Gotou and tells Shinichi to run away.

If anyone know what this track is called, that'll be great.

Comment: There is actually no need to ask such questions here. You can simply go to Animenewsnetwork.com. I believe all the songs, OPs/EDs as well as insert songs pertaining to a certain anime can be found there. Sorry if I'm sounding rude, but this is so that you won't need to ask music request questions here anymore. Here is the link where you will find what you are looking for: https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=15855.   If it isn't there as well, or you have already searched there, please mention that along with your question.

Answer (score 3):

Found it. Apparently there's a [special OST](http://vgmdb.net/album/53967) and it's the song named "creep".